# Attribute Error in Django: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models, error-handling

Here are the list of models in models.py

```
CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
    ('S', "Shirt"),  # (what goes into DB, Shown text)
    ('SW', "Sports wears"),
    ('OW', "Outwears")
]

LABEL_CHOICES = [
    ('P', "primary"),  # (what goes into DB, Shown text)
    ('S', "secondary"),
    ('D', "danger")
]


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default="No Title Added")
    price = models.FloatField(max_length=3, default=0.00, blank=False)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, blank=False, default='S')
    label = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=LABEL_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    discount_price = models.FloatField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=False, default='Slug-1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('item_detailview', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse('add_to_cart', kwargs={
            'slug': self.slug
        })


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem),
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True),
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

All the views work fine but the problem is with "add_to_cart" function. Here is the function

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()

        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)

    return redirect("add_to_cart", slug=slug)
```

Here the **"order.items.add(order_item)"** and **"order.items.filter()"** fails with an Attribute Error mentioned above. I tried with with different versions of Django but the problem still persist.

Comment: You have a trailing comma at the `items = ManyToManyField(...)`, as a result you did not create the relation, since this you wrapped the field in a singleton tuple.

Comment: The same on the next line btw.